# Using multiple WebSocket clients inside automated Selenium tests with unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, websocket

I am writing automated UI tests for a specific device, where the UI configurations are transferred to the device from a back-end server as multiple JSON files over websocket connections. At first, I wrote a small separate script that receives websocket messages, saves them to JSON files and closes the websocket connection. Then when I ran my test in another file, I could access the JSON files and process the configuration info in my test.

What I want to do however is to integrate this websocket connection inside the tests, so I will only run a test and it will handle everything. I tried to do this but the test gets stuck listening to the websocket and it cannot navigate in the UI, a next step in the test which would trigger the message transfer.

I am running the tests on Windows 10 in an Anaconda virtual environment with Python 2.7.14 and using ChromeDriver for Selenium 3.11.0. The websocket library is the 0.2.1 version.

Here is the code I used:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import json
from lib import *
import sys
import unittest
import websocket
import xmlrunner


class TestCases(TestObject):

    def test_service_recharge(self):

        # Step 1: Login and initialize websocket client
        credential = self.get_data()["credentials"][0]
        login_page = LoginPage(self.get_driver(), url=self.get_url())
        login_page.load_page()
        login_page.try_login(credential["username"], credential["password"])

        ws = websocket.WebSocket()
        ws.connect("ws://192.168.1.105:8888/gui/services/menudata")
        print "Receiving websocket messages..."
        menu_data = ws.recv()

        # Step 2: Check successful login 
        services_page = ServicesPage(self.get_driver())
        services_page.check_opened()

        # Step 3: Save websocket message to a .json file
        menu_data_json = json.loads(menu_data)

        with open('PATH_TO_FILE\\Services_Menu_Recharge_JSON.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(menu_data_json, outfile)

        ws.close()

        # Step 4: Start a new websocket client to get a second, different message
        ws = websocket.WebSocket()
        ws.connect("ws://192.168.1.105:8888/gui/services/servicesdata")
        print "Receiving websocket messages..."
        menu_data = ws.recv()

        # Step 5: Navigate to another page and save the obtained message to a local file
        services_page.go_to_recharge()
        recharge_page = RechargePage(self.get_driver())
        recharge_page.check_opened()

        menu_data_json = json.loads(menu_data)

        with open('PATH_TO_FILE\\Services_Components_Recharge_JSON.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(menu_data_json, outfile)

        ws.close()

        # Step 6: Work with the locally saved json files
        parser = JsonParser()
        service_components_list = parser.read_all_nodes()

        # Rest of the test #

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(
        output='test-reports'), failfast=False, buffer=False, catchbreak=False)
```

And here is where it gets stuck:

```
Running tests...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
[17364:19032:0705/163445.321:ERROR:install_util.cc(597)] Unable to read registry value HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken for writing result=2

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12069/devtools/browser/a91244ef-8daf-422e-a24a-ca0e19218aa1
Receiving websocket messages...
```

I guess the test script is listening to a websocket message from the address I provide and does not continue until a message is received.

How can I handle this issue so that the client listens to a websocket message with a timeout limit and saves/shares the received message so it can be accessed from within the test script *concurrently* as the test steps continue running?

Thanks in advance for your attention and for your replies.

Comment: While sending the data from the server, are you flushing the socket?

Comment: Hi @ShivamMishra, no I am not. I am simply using [the example on websocket module's GitHub page for one-off send & receive.](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client#short-lived-one-off-send-receive)

Comment: It seems socket is not able to know when your message is over since you have not specified number of bytes to receive. Can you try adding socket.send("") on your server side after the entire data is sent?

Comment: I don't have access to the server that sends the configuration files over websocket, I only want to create a client that listens to the messages it sends inside the test script. The part I couldn't get past is: I want to initate the client before I activate the trigger (navigating to a certain page) that sends a message over websocket, so it gets stuck at listening since no messages are coming.

Comment: Ok. Yeah I do get your problem. If you dont have access to server side send logic, what you can do is receive a fixed number of bytes like this: ws.recv(1024). (Check if 1024 bytes are enough to receive your entire data by printing it, if not increase the number of bytes or receive it in chunks of 1024 bytes in a loop.) Additionally, do you know what is the last character of your message?

Comment: Actually the contents of the configuration files are always changing, so I am not sure if I can rely on their content - size. I was hoping to perhaps facilitate multi-threading of some sort for this issue, but I don't know how to implement that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174504/discussion-between-reincore-and-shivam-mishra).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had needed was to use **threading**, apparently. I had used different threads for the websocket client and for the automated tests.

I had used the *threading* library to achieve this and made the threads that run the websocket clients daemon threads. This solved my problem.